# Create two (junit) test functions

Tags: java, junit

I tried to write my two first test functions which are simple.

The first function that I want to test is a create function :

```
    public Milestone create(Milestone milestone) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    milestone.setId(id);

    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/dao_db", "sa", "");
    PreparedStatement prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MILESTONE VALUES(?, ?,?)");

    prepareStatement.setString(1, id);
    prepareStatement.setString(2, milestone.getName());
    prepareStatement.setString(3, milestone.getDescription());
    prepareStatement.executeUpdate();

    connection.close();
    return milestone;}
```

The second one is an update function :

```
    public Milestone update(Milestone milestone) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/dao_db", "sa", "");
    PreparedStatement prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE MILESTONE SET NAME=?, DESCRIPTION = ? WHERE ID=?");

    prepareStatement.setString(1, milestone.getName());
    prepareStatement.setString(2, milestone.getDescription());
    prepareStatement.setString(3, milestone.getId());
    prepareStatement.executeUpdate();

    connection.close();     
    return milestone;};
```

Then, I tried to write these two functions :

```
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import java.sql.SQLException; 
    import org.junit.Test;
    import model.Milestone;

    public class MilestoneDAOImplTest {

@Test
public void createTest() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    MilestoneDAOImpl ms = new MilestoneDAOImpl();
    Milestone milestone = new Milestone("test","test");
    assertNotNull("milestone created", ms.create(milestone));   }

@Test
public void updateTest() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    MilestoneDAOImpl ms = new MilestoneDAOImpl();
    Milestone milestone = new Milestone("test","test");
    assertNotNull("milestone updated", ms.update(milestone));   }
```

Can you tell me please if these two test functions are correct or not? Because I found that a bit pointless to do tests like that. I mean that in my createTest function for example, the only verification is the

```
    assertNotNull("milestone created", ms.create(milestone));
```

But I can also verify that in my main class by doing the same thing (the same function ms.create(milestone). So, what's the real utility of such tests? (if these tests are correct?) I didn't see a real difference (I'm newbie in Java).

Comment: As part of assertion you can also check for the record if it got created successfully by trying to retrieve the same record with some readFunctions and verifying the values..Also if you are using this test methods in some context like to be viewed on some screen then you can also add that check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test class, you can additionally check below
1. For each of the exception thrown, you can assert if particular exceptions are thrown at particular scenarios.
For eg.

```
   @Test
   public void createTest() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
   try{
   MilestoneDAOImpl ms = new MilestoneDAOImpl();
Milestone milestone = new Milestone("test","test");
assertNotNull("milestone updated", ms.update(milestone));   
}catch (ClassNotFoundException e1)
{
// do some assertions based on scenarios like some relevent jars are missed in classpath
}
catch (SQLException e2)
{
// do some assertions like wrong connection URL etc.
}
}
```

2. Assert if insert & update operations actully executed in DB as desired.
   Create select method in DAO layer,

   ```
   public Milestone select(String milestoneId) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
   select * from MILESTONE  where ID=milestoneId
   transform resultset into Milestone object
   return MilestoneObject;
   }
   ```

And call it from your test method to assert 
For eg.

```
   @Test
   public void updateTest() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
MilestoneDAOImpl ms = new MilestoneDAOImpl();
Milestone milestone = new Milestone("test","test");
assertNotNull("milestone updated", ms.update(milestone));  
Milestone milestone1=ms.select(milestone.getId());

assertEquals(milestone1.getName(),milestone.getName());
assertEquals(milestone1.getdescrition(),milestone.getDescription());
        }
```

Hope this helps.